# How to get long from byte array returned by jmrtd's sendGetChallenge (used to get passport random number)

Tags: java, android, arrays, byte, long-integer

I'm using jmrtd library on android to get and process passport information.

The first step is to send a challenge to the passport so it responds with a random 64 bit number as a byte array (8 bytes).

The function sendGetChallenge returns a byte array.

I need to print out this byte array as a number to make analysis but I'm having trouble converting the byte array returned to long, mainly because I'm not sure if this array is big endian or little endian.

So far I've used the following methods:

```
public static long byteArrayToLong(byte[] bytes){
    long value = 0;
    value += (long) (bytes[7] & 0x000000FF) << 56;
    value += (long) (bytes[6] & 0x000000FF) << 48;
    value += (long) (bytes[5] & 0x000000FF) << 40;
    value += (long) (bytes[4] & 0x000000FF) << 32;
    value += (bytes[3] & 0x000000FF) << 24;
    value += (bytes[2] & 0x000000FF) << 16;
    value += (bytes[1] & 0x000000FF) << 8;
    value += (bytes[0] & 0x000000FF);
    return value;
}
```

Or

```
private long byteArrayToLong(byte[] buffer){
    long value=0;
    long multiplier=1;
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) { //get from the right
        value=value+(buffer[i] & 0xff)*multiplier; 
        multiplier=multiplier <<8;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Or

```
public static long bytesToLong(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE);
    buffer.put(bytes);
    buffer.flip();
    return buffer.getLong();
}
```

Or

```
byte[] randomNumber = sendGetChallenge();    
new BigInteger(randomNumber).toString();
```

But I'm getting (sometimes) negative values which is obviously wrong.

Can someone help me on why am I getting negative values, or if someone know how to get the long value from the byte array returned by the sendGetChallenge function from jmrtd library.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That negative isn't wrong.  What's happening is that long is a signed number, so if the first bit of your byte array is a 1 it will turn the entire number negative.  Its holding the right value, but it will display as a negative.  The solution is to either deal with it or not use a long (use a BigInteger or a String).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The thing is, the number must not be negative, so I can stop using a long, but I've used BigInteger and still get a negative.

Comment: BigIntegers are also signed.  If you want to use a BigInteger, you need to make sure the MSB is not a 1.  Easiest way to do that is to pass in 0 as the first byte in the byte array, then the data after that.

Comment: So to be clear, should I force the first byte to be 0? I mean, I get an 8 positions byte array as the response from the function, so should I 'insert' a 0 as the first byte? if that is correct, should it be the 0 or the 8? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, insert a 0 in the first position.  BigInteger assumes the array is in network byte order (big-endian), so the most significant bit is the first one.  Forcing that MSB to 0 will force the number to be positive.  IF the MSB is negative the entire number is treated as a 2's complement negative number.

Comment: I did it, in a test I got this number 15761629304742585754. The biggest number I could get for a possitive 64 bit number is (2^64)-1 is that correct? I mean, in my case I'm working with an unisgned value, am I right?